# Xamarin.Android Build Error after target sdk change

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

Getting the following error in my MainActivity.cs in my Android project of a Xamarin.Forms solution:
`CurrentPlatform is inacessbile due to its protection level`

From the following line of code which is inside the OnCreate(), with only the CurrentPlaftorm portion underlined:
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();`

I didn't receive this error until I upgraded my MonoAndroid to v7.0 from v6.0 and did all the necessary updates that come with that like JDK 1.8.
Wondering if someone can explain what this error means and why it is being invoke specifically for the CurrentPlatform.

I tried to recreate this error in a new project but once I typed `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.` it had the CurrentPlatform option available with no issue.

Also now a line using the `MobileServiceClient` type calling the LoginAsync() from the WindowsAzure component throws two errors on the parameters which used to be:

`await client.LoginAsync(context, "facebook");`

But I receive the following two errors now:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Context' to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider'`
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'`

Not sure why these two areas of code broke when I changed my Android Target SDK as they were just part of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure components.

Comment: The LoginAsync method has changed I guess to something like `client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token)` where `token` is an optional JObject token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure why these two areas of code broke when I changed my Android Target SDK as they were just part of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure components.

According to your description, I assumed that it dues to the version of [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) you referenced.

- For [Azure Mobile Client SDK 3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/3.1.0), you client would reference the lib from the following path:

  `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.1.0\lib\monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll`

  You could leverage [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to check the extension methods for `LoginAsync` as follows:
  [image]

While for [Azure Mobile Client SDK 4.0.0-alpha-001](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/4.0.0-alpha-001), if your MonoAndroid >= 4.4, then the lib would be reference under:

`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.4.0.0-alpha-001\lib\monoandroid44\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll`[image]

- For [Azure Mobile Client SDK 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/4.0.0), if your MonoAndroid >= 7.1, then the lib would be reference under:

  `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client\4.0.0\lib\monoandroid71\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll`

  My previous project targets on Android 6.0, then the lib would only reference `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.4.0.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.dll`, and there has no extension methods for `LoginAsync` via server-flow authentication.

In summary, from your code `await client.LoginAsync(context, "facebook");`, you are using [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow), I would recommend that you could use Azure Mobile Client SDK 3.1.0 without upgrading your Android SDK version or use the latest Azure Mobile Client SDK 4.0.0 and upgrading your Android SDK version to 7.1 or higher.

Additionally, the code `client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebo‌​ok,{JObject token})` is using [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow), at this point, your app can independently contact the identity provider and then provide the returned token during login with your azure mobile backend.

Comment: I was able to revert the Azure Mobile Client SDK back to 3.1.0 and now its working again. thank you for pointing me in the right direction.